# Text box entry in a GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

For a class I am coding a small Chess simulator with a GUI using python. To enter a move I would like to have a text box that you can type in, and once you press the **btn** move, it moves that piece.

Currently I have the GUI with radio buttons for each piece. Under the function for the btn to move them I have:

```
if btn == 4:
   cmds.select('A4')
   cmds.move()
```

I however do not know how to write a code for a simple text box in a gui or what the propper code to reference the text box is.

Q: *How to code a simple working text box, and how to write the code so the functions can reference the gui.*

Answer (score 2):

We can create the text box using the [textField](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/textField.html) command. To create a typical textField command:

```
my_textfield = cmds.textField()
```

In Maya, every UI element has a unique identifier name string. When we call the textField command in create mode, it will return the name of the textField it created. Here, `my_textfield` would be a Python variable that contains the name of the created textField that we can refer to later. To access the text value of this textField we would do something like:

```
text_entered = cmds.textField(my_textfield, query=True, text=True)
```

Here, to access the text entered in the textField, we are calling the textField command in query mode, by setting the query flag as True and setting the text flag as True. Setting `text=True` in query mode, i.e. `query=True` tells the command to return the current text value of the textField. Now `text_entered` would be the Python variable that will contain the text entered.

Text fields can take any sort of textual inputs that might need validation. To avoid validation troubles you could use the [intField](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/intField.html) if you know that the inputs need to be only integers. (There is also a floatField.) Using an intField is also very similar to textField. To create one:

```
my_intfield = cmds.intField(minValue=1, maxValue=8)
```

`minValue` and `maxValue` are optional parameters that let you set the minimum and maximum values that this field can accept. To access the value entered:

```
val_entered = cmds.intField(my_intfield, query=True, value=True)
```

Have a look at the documentation for these two fields for more information on what else they offer:

- [textField](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/textField.html)
- [intField](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/intField.html)